# User Authentication with SHA512

Tags: php, mysql, hash, openvpn, sha512

I am hashing passwords before they are entered into the database using the following code:

```
$user_password = hash( 'sha512', $_POST['user_pass'] );
```

I followed a this [this](http://chagridsada.blogspot.com/2011/01/openvpn-system-based-on-userpass.html) tutorial to authenticate OpenVPN users via a mySQL database. In it, we setup the following file which I believe authenticates requests against the mySQL database. The script is: 
"**/etc/openvpn/script/login.sh**" and it consists of the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /etc/openvpn/script/config.sh
##Authentication
user_id=$(mysql -h$HOST -P$PORT -u$USER -p$PASS $DB -sN -e "select user_id from user where user_id = '$username' AND user_pass = '$password' AND user_enable=1 AND user_start_date != user_end_date AND TO_DAYS(now()) >= TO_DAYS(user_start_date) AND (TO_DAYS(now()) <= TO_DAYS(user_end_date) OR user_end_date='0000-00-00')")
##Check user
[ "$user_id" != '' ] && [ "$user_id" = "$username" ] && echo "user : $username" && echo 'authentication ok.' && exit 0 || echo 'authentication failed.'; exit 1
```

This works as long as the password is not being hashed. How can I use this same method but authenticate users that have a hashed password?

Answer (score 1):

The SHA* hash functions are not appropriate for passwords because they are ways too fast. Have a look at the PHP function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), it will generate a BCrypt hash and takes care of the generation of a safe salt. There exist also a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for older PHP versions.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

This also means that you cannot verify the password directly within the SQL statement, instead in a first step read the hash from the database (by username), afterwards call password_verify() with this hash.